# How to use multiple If Then statements in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I need help in correctly running the below given VBA code.

What I'm trying to do is check for set of cells if they have value 1.

If **True**, then a MsgBox comes up prompting user to enter a correct value and stops the script from running further.

If **False**, then the script moves to the next line of If-Then statement.

If all the statements are False, then the script finally saves the active sheet and moves to next sheet in the workbook.

**Issue**

My script does not **Stop** when a statement is **True**. I tried using Exit Sub and followed by End If after every If & Then statement but the code does not work as intended

I'm new to any form of coding and the below code is the best I could come up with. If there is any optimized way of doing this then I'm ok to understand it and implement the same.

```
Sub BasicInfo()

If Range("C5").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please enter a Name!")
If Range("C6").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please enter your Designation!")
If Range("C8").Value = 1 Then MsgBox ("Please enter your Gender!")
If Range("C9").Value = 1 Then MsgBox ("Please enter Years of Experience!")
If Range("C10").Value = 1 Then MsgBox ("Please enter Years of Experience in present Job!")
If Range("C11").Value = 1 Then MsgBox ("Please enter your Date of Birth!")
If Range("D11").Value = 1 Then MsgBox ("Please enter your Month of Birth!")
If Range("E11").Value = 1 Then MsgBox ("Please enter your Year of Birth!")
If Range("C12").Value = 1 Then MsgBox ("Please enter marital Status!")
If Range("C13").Value = 1 Then MsgBox ("Please enter your Enducation!")
If Range("C14").Value = 1 Then MsgBox ("Please enter your Nationality!")

ActiveWorkbook.Save
Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
```

End Sub

Comment: Each If statement is self-contained and so each will be checked. You need to nest the If-Else probably, but your conditions are not mutually exclusive (or are they)?

Comment: Hi SJR
Well, I was not able to successfully use Else statement initially and my conditions are exclusive to one of the sheets and common on the rest 2 sheets that I plan to use the script on.
Thanks

Comment: So if C5 is blank then should nothing else be checked? If that is the case you need the Else - what did you try?

Comment: Ok, if C5 is empty (meaning Value 1 as Im using a Combo Box dropdown with blank option = 1)
Then, the MsgBox pops-up and the script stops from running as the user needs to enter data into C5. If C5 is not 1 (or empty) then the script should move to check cell C6. This goes on until all the mentioned cells are checked. I hope I managed to explain it.

Comment: It would be easier to use Data Validations

Comment: I used Else operator like this
`Sub BasicInfo()
    
    If Range("C5").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please enter a Name!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
    
    If Range("C6").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please enter your Designation!")`

Comment: Perhaps `If Range("C5").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please enter a Name!"):Exit Sub` etc, but this is only checked when you run the macro.

Comment: @PankajJaju
Generally Data Validations would work as you suggested but I was asked to use script for reasons best known to the management. Thanks

Comment: @SJR: Let me try using `:Exit Sub` option on every Cell. But yes, I see what you saying that it only checks when the macro runs. I guess On File closing, I can trigger the macro. Not sure if it's possible I'm thinking loud.

Comment: @SJR
Using `:Exit Sub` on every cell worked. But I need to explore how I can trigger the macro when User tries to Saves & closes the workbook.
Thanks!

Comment: OK. Look at Worksheet/Workbook events.

Comment: @SJR
Sure, will do. Appreciate your time and help.